# Rails. "unitialized Contsant Object::Contact"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm working through the Ruby on Rails Bible using Windows 7 and Rails 3 + mysql.
I created a database and a table in mysql directly as per instructions. 
Then I created a model called Contact
Next in irb I entered:
my_contact=Contact.new and then I get the error:
"unitialized constant Object::Contact"

I think perhaps I have to precede the code with a require statement or perhaps I need to install a gem? Except I haven't a clue beyond that at this stage as I'm a newbie...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running irb manually, run `rails console`, this should load all dependencies for your app. Also make sure you have run `rake db:migrate` before starting the console.

Comment: Thanks for the superfast answer! but now I'm stuck again... "Object doesn't support #inspect"

Comment: I'm trying to create a new contact model object and I entered: my_contact=Contact.new

Comment: Do you have a constructor for your Contact model? May be easier to know what's going on if you post the relevant code.

Comment: eh what's a contructor? I'm just following exactly what's in the book. I did enter 'rails generate model Contact' to create the model. The book never mentioned rake db:migrate or anything about constructors. I'm starting to find it's not very straightforward. There's a file called Contact.rb wtih the following default code: class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base



end
Is that what you're talking about?

Comment: I don't know the book :) `rails generate model Contact` will only create an empty model and a migration for you. See in the db/migrate directory and fill out what fields you want in the model. The `rake db:migrate` loads the changes into the actual database. See here for a good guide on making a small app: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Comment: here's the code in db/migrate:class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :contacts do |t|

      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :contacts
  end
end
I just assumed that if I followed all the steps in the book that I should then be able to create an object. I'll check out that link though - thanks for your help...